# Using Raspberry Pi to deliver POE to other products through the ethernet port

Tags: usb, pi-4, camera, modem, poe

Scenario is this:

Have a raspberry pi being powered through a usb-c adapter.

Have a 3g usb modem, that connects the pi to the internet.

Have a camera device connected to the ethernet port of the raspberry pi, which powers the camera, and also the raspberry pi acts as a dhcp server for the camera, giving it a local ip address.

Is this even possible?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from putting a 40-60V on the POE header, but most would use an injector.

Comment: The Pi will not produce PoE voltages on Ethernet lines.